# Layout Service Sending Sitecore Item Name instead of Component Name

Tags: jss, layout-service

I have a brand new `Sitecore 10` site, with `SXA` and `JSS` installed. I have migrated an accelerator site we built for `Sitecore 9.3`, so it is possible that this behaviour was introduced, however it does not appear in the 9.3 version of the site from which it was taken so seems unlikely.

The issue I"m experiencing is that the `Sitecore Layout Service` is sending the Sitecore Item Name to the componentName field in the jss json payload. I can verify that it does this for every `jss rendering`, and can also verify that changing the sitecore Item Name to match the Component Name fixes the component (it renders as the name matches the manifest).

Has anyone seen behaviour like this before?  Any suggestions on where I can look to find the source of the issue?

Here's a screenshot, for clarity:
[image]

Thanks heaps

Greg

Comment: Could you check what is the Component Name field ID?

Comment: Field ID should be {037FE404-DD19-4BF7-8E30-4DADF68B27B0}

Comment: Field ID is {037FE404-DD19-4BF7-8E30-4DADF68B27B0}

Answer (score 1):

So I've updated JSS to 15.0.1 and it fixes the componentName issue. It seems there's a bug in Sitecore 10 and Jss that was fixed in 15.0.1.  Strange that it wasn't mentioned anywhere in the release notes, but thanks to Vincent Lui for the inspiration to give it a try.

Now to get it into our images...

Comment: I am facing the same componentName issue on Sitecore 10.0.1 with JSS 15.0.1, would you share if any further steps are required to resolve the issue?